# Not loading properly in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, image

The problem is that sometimes  it's don't show the picture. The HTTP response contains the code 304 and it's say the picture is loaded but it is not.
Sometimes it works perfectly. But I don't understand how to solve it. Please help me. Thanks.

HTML:-

```
<div class="mycontainer">
    <div class="clickable">
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <img ng-src="{{ $ctrl.url }}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS/CSS:-

```css
.mycontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 475px;
  height: 132px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;

  .clickable {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;

    .imagecontainer {
       display: inline-block;
       float: left;
       width: 150px;
       margin-right: 17px;

        img {
            width: 150px;
        }
      }

    .details {

      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      width: 245px;

    }
   }

}
```

pictureComponent:-

```
import './picture.scss';

/*@ngInject*/
class PictureComponentController {

  constructor() {
    'ngInject';

      if (this.image) {
        this.url = 'pic1.png';
      } else {
        this.url = 'pic2.png';
      }
    }

  }

}

export default class PictureComponent {

  constructor() {
    this.template = require('./picture.html');
    this.bindings = {
      image: "<image"
      alt: '@oAlt'
    };

    this.controller = PictureComponentController;
  }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like your DOM is loading before your request has resolved. Can you post the Javascript you use to get the image?

Comment: I think it has some problem with the css because right now I noticed that the height of the container is 60px, but it should be 312px.